# No puedo pasar parametros de una página JSF a otra

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

Sucede que al momento de pasar parametros de una página JSF, mediante un button de primefaces, hacia otra página JSF usando su url, la primera vez que mando los parametros no los manda, pero la segunda vez sí los manda.

Código del botón:

```
<p:button outcome="report_supervision_vehicle.xhtml"
          id="btnPdf"
          target="_blank"
          title="PDF"
          class="btn-pdf"
          style="display: ${listado.stylePdf?'inline':'none'}"
          value="">
   <f:param name="folio" value="${listado.folio}" />
   <f:param name="modulo" value="${listado.modulo}" />
   <f:param name="firma1" value="${listado.va1}" />
   <f:param name="firma2" value="${listado.va2}" />
   <f:param name="firma3" value="${listado.va3}" />
   <f:param name="firma4" value="${listado.va4}" />
</p:button>
```

Código para recibir los parámetros:

```
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="folio" value="#{listado.folio}" />
   <f:viewParam name="modulo" value="#{listado.modulo}" />
   <f:viewParam name="firma1" value="#{listado.va1}" />
   <f:viewParam name="firma2" value="#{listado.va2}" />
   <f:viewParam name="firma3" value="#{listado.va3}" />
   <f:viewParam name="firma4" value="#{listado.va4}" />
   <f:viewAction action="#{listado.onLoad}" />
</f:metadata>
```

el java script este toma un string tipo json y lo transoforma a bytes base 64 y con remotecommand jama un metodo que sete a este valor en las variables va1, va2 , va3 etc. y almandarlas como parametros en la url creo que se tarda en ejecutar el javascript que lo mando a llamar con el execute de request context en el bean

```
<script>
            //<![CDATA[

            function getImageTemporary(jsonData, canvas) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas);
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                canvas.height = 100;
                canvas.width = 250;
                context.fillStyle = "green";
                jsonData = verifyJson(jsonData);
                console.log(jsonData);
                if (jsonData !== false && jsonData !== null) {
                    array = jsonData;
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.lineJoin = "round";
                    context.lineWidth = 2;
                    for (a = 0; a < array["lines"].length; a++) {
                        linea = array["lines"][a];
                        for (b = 0; b < linea.length; b++) {
                            coordenadas = linea[b];
                            if (b === 0) {
                                context.moveTo(coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]);
                            }
                            context.lineTo(coordenadas[0], coordenadas[1]);
                        }
                    }
                    context.stroke();

                    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
                }
                return false;
            }

            function verifyJson(json) {
                try {
                    return jQuery.parseJSON(json);
                } catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function chargeImage(json1, json2, json3, json4) {
                var image1 = getImageTemporary(json1, "canvas1");
                var image2 = getImageTemporary(json2, "canvas2");
                var image3 = getImageTemporary(json3, "canvas3");
                var image4 = getImageTemporary(json4, "canvas4");
                console.log(image1);
                console.log(image2);
                console.log(image3);
                console.log(image4);
                firma1([{name: 'firma1', value: image1}]);
                firma2([{name: 'firma2', value: image2}]);
                firma3([{name: 'firma3', value: image3}]);
                firma4([{name: 'firma4', value: image4}]);
                console.log("paso");
            }
            //&&
            //]]>

        </script>
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar, si hay algo que no me di a entender con gusto lo pondré. Quedo pendiente, saludos y excelente día.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son los alcances/ámbitos (scope) de los Managed Beans que intervienen?  (aparte de listado ¿cuál otro?)

Comment: Hola, solo es uno y es viewScope, las variables va1 se settean con javascript.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, volvi a editar mi pregunta, puse el javascript donde realiza las funcionalidades. Saludos

Comment: ¿Necesitas pasarlos de esa manera con Javascript?